# android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android, xml

So I don't see where it is casting it into `android.view.ViewGroup` I get this error message when I try to view my xml in the graphic view. I haven't done anything to the actual java this pertains too.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_divider_holo_light" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

Here I tired to make a style with these elements and it wouldn't accept it.

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="@string/add_alarm"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ff505050"
            android:textSize="18.0sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSetTimer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100.0dp"
            android:text="Button" />
    </TableRow>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSetAlarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2.0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/list_divider_holo_light" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="20.0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40.0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="25.0dip"
                android:text="@string/alarm_volume_title" />
        </TableRow>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/default_volume_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dp"
            android:paddingTop="2.0dip" />
    </TextView>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The text view `textView2` is **not closed** (it is just before closing the table `layout`), and the runtime is trying to cast it to a `viewgroup` in order to add the 2 table rows and `seekbar`.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to put other elements inside your `TextView` (`@+id/textView2`). That's not valid because as the error says, it's not a `ViewGroup`.