# android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-widget, textview

cannot find the source of this error. 
Saw other questions concerning the same problem, which is often caused by a missing closing-tag. But cannot find which one is missing in my code...

My main activity.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/main_textview"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#FFF8DC"
    android:padding="@dimen/component_padding"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/simplefragment"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/component_padding"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And one for a Fragment:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat says:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.melle.androidfragments/com.example.melle.androidfragments.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

Comment: are you trying to use the TextView as container for a Fragment ?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526264/android-widget-textview-cannot-be-cast-to-android-view-viewgroup

Comment: @Blackbelt Indeed I want to use it as a Container for a Fragment, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use TextView. Use a FrameLayout.

Comment: Which one shall I edit?

Answer (score 1):

`Viewgroup` means a view that can have other views inside it. You're opening and closing your TextViews separately, making them a group when they can't.

Based on the code you posted, the solution would be to remove all `</TextView>` and close it directly at the end of the attributes with `/>`, like this, for example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/simplefragment"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/component_padding"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Do this in all of your TextViews. Also,check if there is some `<TextView>` tag with any other view inside it, if so then you should remove it and put somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have findViewById that specific textview and casted it to be a ViewGroup so eg:

> ViewGroup simpleFragment = (ViewGroup)
>   findViewById(R.id.simplefragment);

You cannot cast the textview to a viewGroup because it is not a ViewGroup, textview is a View.

If you look at the android docs, textview extends View: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

ViewGroups are objects like RelativeLayout or LinearLayouts or FrameLayouts which can contain multiple views within them.